# connect to an access database on a network share with javascript

Tags: javascript, database, internet-explorer-11, ado, network-share

I need to create a database with about 65000 products and their specifications. All I have to work with is a network drive, access 2007 and a browser (IE11).

So far, I have successfully connected to the database with html/javascript on a local drive, however it fails when I try to connect to it from a networked computer.

See the code below:

```
  var strPath = "file://mynetworkshare/n/tecdoc/tecdoc.accdb";                                      

  var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + strPath;
  var objConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");

  objConn.Open(strConn);

  var objRs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  objRs.Open(strSql, objConn, ADO_RS_CTE_AD_OPEN_KEYSET, ADO_RS_LTE_AD_LOCK_PESSIMISTIC);
```

The code clearly fails at `objConn.Open(strConn)` therefor I tried multiple forms of local network URL's to put in the `strPath` ... yet, none worked. I'm starting to suspect that my approach isn't possible. Any and all insights on the matter are welcome!

Comment: I suspect this may be a limitation of IE11. Have you tried running the script using the Windows Script Host directly rather than through the browser? The executable is available at C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe or, if you need the 32-bit version on a 64-bit system, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe. I don't know if this is the source of the problem, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: I got the same result using cscript, at least it did confirm my suspicion. The script keeps hanging at the "objConn.open" statement as it can't find the database I am trying to point at.

Comment: I have tried something similar before, and although it was a nightmare, I never had this problem. But since you invite any and all insights, I'll take another stab at it. First, Have you made sure that the networked computer has the relevant drivers installed? What happens if you try to connect to a local database on *that* computer? Second, have you tried to determine if it was a problem with the permissions or security settings on the network? Finally, have you tried creating a database on the networked computer and linking to the main database in Access? What happens when you do that?

Comment: After changing the browser security settings on the networked windows 7 machines the script worked perfect, however the windows 10 machines still fail. I am pretty sure now that it is a driver issue. Sadly, even if I knew what todo about that, I do not have the administrative rights to do so. I am gonna abandon this approach and start developping my fallback solution which is far less elegant but proofed to be working. I do greatly appreciate your efforts, thank you McMath!

Comment: No problem. I'm only sorry I couldn't have been more help. Just in case you are able to get administrative rights to install the correct drivers, I seem to recall that I had a similar issue, and it was just a matter of downloading and installing either [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39358) or [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255). (I think it was the latter, even though I was connecting to Access 2013).